# Cakephp "virtual" model name to use with another DB

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, model, cakephp-2.0

I Have this scenario:

There is ONE datebase with the table *contactgroups*.
**One** Cakephp 2 project that uses this table for the model *Contactgroup*.

Now there comes a **second** Cakephp 2 instance/project that also uses that database.
 However the model shall be called *Tag* in this project for several reasons. Therefore it would require the table to be named *tags*. But it has to use the table *contactgroups* in that DB and behave as if itself were named *Contactgroup* (meaning to serve data as model *Contactgroup* and using *contactgroup_id* in associated models on database layer). In the Cakephp App it always uses *Tag*, also for saving/loading data.

How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create model named `Tag` in second project and then set model field called `$useTable`.

```
class Tag extends AppModel {

   public $useTable = 'contactgroups';

}
```

[Here](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/model-attributes.html#usetable) you can read more about this model attribute.

Comment: does this also work with associated models/tables that use contactgroup_id ?

Comment: You can always define custom `$primaryKey` in model or define it while you are setting up a association in connected model.